# Как обозначить переменную из c++ в Python?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, типы-данных

Перевожу код из с++ в Python и столкнулся с таким определением переменной:

```
unsigned int ch[110][2]
```

Правильно ли я это обозначил для Python?

```
ch = [[[0], [1]]]*110
```

Comment: Если вы портируете из С++ на Python массивы, посмотрите на NumPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае массив, который состоит из 110 элементов, каждый из которых является массивом с 2 элементами типа unsigned int

Вы сделали неправильно, корректно сделать так:

```
ch = [[0,0] for i in range(110)]
```